# How to use wildcards to remove print pages from search engines?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, search-engine-indexing

Our site has pages that are print-friendly, which I would like to remove from search engines.

Here's an example: http://rubinarealestate.com/en/property/apartments-charming-neighborhood/?pid=4940&print=1 is the print-version of http://rubinarealestate.com/en/property/apartments-charming-neighborhood/

I assume this can be done with *robots.txt* and wildcards, as the `?pid=4940&print=1` is always at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is as easy as including this disallow rule in your *robots.txt* file:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /*print=1
```

That will only work for bots that actually support wildcards in *robots.txt*. Google, Bing, and Yahoo all do, but minor search engines may not.

You could also configure your server to include a [meta robots noindex directive](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in the print version of the page:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
```